# Trying to update MYSQL table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to update a MYSQL table in PHP but it doesn't seem to be working. I tweak the code and sometimes it says it has updated, when it hasn't and other times it says it didn't work. If anybody could have a look at my code and tell me if they can see anything wrong that would be much appreciated.

**Form:**

```
<form method="post" action="update.php" name="update" id="update">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="regUsername" value="<?php echo $row['username'] ?>" /><br><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="regPassword"  value="<?php echo $row['password'] ?>" /><br><br>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="regEmail" value="<?php echo $row['email'] ?>" /><br><br>
<p id="FillInFields"></p>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/><br>
</form>
```

**Update.php**

```
<?php
$linkme = mysql_connect("*******","******","******");
if (!$linkme)
    die ("Could not connect to database");
mysql_select_db("*******", $linkme);

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["username"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$edit_id = $_POST['edit_id'];


$query = mysql_query(
    "UPDATE user 
    SET username = '$username' , 
    password = '$password' , 
    email = '$email' 
    WHERE user_id = '$edit_id'");

mysql_query ($query)
    or die ("Sorry but your details were not uploaded.");

echo ("Your details didn't update");

mysql_close($linkme);
?>
```

**edit_id is the session id that is on the form page:** and the session has been started inside all pages using sessions.

```
$edit_id = $_SESSION['edit_id'];
```

Thank you

Comment: There's no reference for `edit_id` in your form, nor a closing `</form>`. If those are part of your production code; post it. In the meantime, Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: No errors reported? *Dang Ralph, you were faster than me*

Comment: @JayBlanchard What can ye do *Sam?!* - Lunch? Ah, now there's a novel idea!

Comment: Light lunch today. Also, the OP is doing `mysql_query(...)` twice @Fred-ii-

Comment: Please, dont use mysql_*, it was deprecated. Use mysqli_ or PDO with PREPARED statements to deny a SQL Injection. If you cant, at least escape edit_id. NEVER EVER TRUST EXTERNAL CONTENT

Comment: There, as per your edit; there's no `edit_id` named element. Where is that supposed to be coming from?

Comment: Ahhhh `$edit_id = $_SESSION['edit_id'];` that's not the same thing as POST as you originally had it `$edit_id = $_POST['edit_id'];`. Did you start the session? Did you assign it to that, for the POST? Error reporting will tell you. Did you use that yet?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Leave some room for this evening's 2oz.'er.

Comment: @Fred-ii- edit_id is the session id that is the users user_id so it updates a particular users details, ive just updated the code

Comment: What did error reporting have to say? and is the session started in all pages using sessions? Plus `$_SESSION['edit_id']` most likely needs to be assigned from POST, probably why.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just used error reporting now and it has said "Notice: Undefined index: edit_id in E:\webareas\ta210\DEL\update.php on line 12" and yeah the session is started in all pages using sessions

Comment: Also @Andrew, `$query` isn't going to contain what you think it contains.

Comment: You probably need to use @JayBlanchard 's trick of adding a hidden attribute to your form, using `name="edit_it"`. Then assign from POST array to sessions array.

Comment: Looking forward to this evening and its 2 ouncers @Fred-ii-, we have some of that Canadian weather today

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ever try out C.C.? Canadian Whiskey *at its finest!*

Comment: @Andrew you say you are using `session_start()`, but there is not one in this code.

Comment: Hey! where's the SELECT function? where did you find : <?php echo $row['username'] ?> .. is that session format? why don't you use ID selector as the variable instead of name? besides, mysql is getting down soon. why adding the post as your session? oh, my god :(

Comment: I know you're saying that *tongue-firmly-in-cheek* @Fred-ii-!

Comment: I think all of our comments have now fallen to an answer given below. @JayBlanchard - *Cheers!* See you soon eh? wink.

Comment: calm down, let our friends try it @Fred-ii- :p

Comment: @JeanGkol lol I know, I'm just kidding ;-) am always keen to finding solutions. I think I'll join Jay in a 2 oz.'er

Comment: Try something like `<input type="hidden" name="edit_id" value="<?php echo $row['id_row'] ?>">` - `['id_row']` being an example of the said row, since you're iterating over some type of fetching of rows from DB. You may need to provide more code though. Since you're using sessions, you'll need to assign that POST array to a sessions array after.

Comment: So @Andrew did that ^ do the trick; where we at? I'm under the impression it should.

Comment: @Fred-ii- this has worked! Thank you!

Comment: @Andrew Great, I will post it as an answer then and you can accept it; deal?

Comment: You're very much welcome Andrew, *cheers*. it's done.

Comment: lolz ... @Fred-ii-, what are you doing? lolz ... good luck Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Comment to answer to close the question since it did work for the OP.*

Try something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="edit_id" value="<?php echo $row['id_row'] ?>">
```

`['id_row']` being an example of the said row, since you're iterating over some type of fetching of rows from DB.

Since you're using sessions, you'll need to assign that POST array to a sessions array after.

---

Sidenote about the use of the deprecated MySQL library you are using:

- Look into using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: that's better choice, andrew. the best one is PDO

Comment: @Andrew You're very much welcome Andrew, I was glad to have been of help, *cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

is your variable $edit_id missing in the form file?

```
<form method="post" action="update.php" name="update" id="update">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="regUsername" value="<?php echo $row['username'] ?>" /><br><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="regPassword"  value="<?php echo $row['password'] ?>" /><br><br>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="regEmail" value="<?php echo $row['email'] ?>" /><br><br>
```

You must to set an input (usualy of type hidden) to put the key id. In your case, the $edit_id

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things I've noticed.

To debug your sql query, seperate your sql query into a var

```
    echo $query = "UPDATE user SET username = '$username', password = '$password', email = '$email' WHERE user_id = '$edit_id'";

    $query = mysql_query($query); //echo the $query in update.php and  
                                  //run the actual query in a sql dialog
                                  //if that doesn't work, then there's 
                                  //something definitely wrong with your 
                                  //query. 


mysql_query ($query)
    or die ("Sorry but your details were not uploaded.");

    echo ("Your details didn't update"); //you have an echo statement in the
                                         //middle of the script in an area 
                                         //without in a conditional loop, it 
                                         //will echo this error message even 
                                         //if the query committed  
                                         //successfully
```

You're also missing $edit_id. You can have a hidden field in your form as

```
<input type="hidden" name="edit_id" value="edit_id_val">
```

You also don't need to put single ticks in your query around the `edit_id` field value because its an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

$linkme = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die('could not connect because of '.mysqli_error())

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($linkme, $_REQUEST["username"]);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($linkme, $_POST["password"]);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($linkme, $_POST["email"]);
$edit_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($linkme, $_POST['edit_id']);


$q = "UPDATE user SET 
username = '$username', 
password = SHA1('$password'), 
email = '$email' 
WHERE user_id = '$edit_id'";

$r = mysqli_query($linkme, $q);

if($r){
echo 'success';
}else{
echo '<p>'.$q.'</p>';
echo '<p>'.mysqli_error($linkme).'</p>';
}
?>
```

you should encrypt the password to using SHA1 or MD5
also you are missing the edit_id

Comment: How will this possibly fix the OP's code, can you explain it? The OP is using sessions.

Comment: *"you should encrypt the password to using SHA1 or MD5"* - **NO!!**. Here, have a read https://www.bentasker.co.uk/blog/security/201-why-you-should-be-asking-how-your-passwords-are-stored - [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) are what should be used.

Comment: this is not about SHA1 or MD5, mate.

Comment: i wasn't saying that was the problem was just for extra security